# nginx, php-fpm, and multiple roots - how to properly try_files?

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

I have a server context which is rooted in a login application. The login application handles, well, logins, and then returns a redirect to "/app" on the same server if a login is successful. The application is rooted elsewhere, which is handled by the location block shown here:

```
location ^~ /app {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/www/website.com/content/public;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

This works just fine, however the $uri getting passed to PHP still contains `/app`, even though I am using alias rather than root. Because of this, the `try_files` directive fails to a `404` unless I link `app -> ./` in `/usr/share/nginx/www/website.com/content/public`.

It's obviously silly to have that link in there, and if that link ever gets lost, bam dead website without an obvious cause.

### The next thing I tried...

Was to remove the `try_files` directive entirely. This allowed me to `rm` the `app` link in my `/public` folder, and PHP had no problem locating the file and executing it. I used that to dump my `$_SERVER` global from PHP, and found that `"SCRIPT_FILENAME" =>  "/usr/share/nginx/www/website.com/content/public/index.php"` when the browser URI is `/app`.

*This is exactly right*. Based on my `fastcgi_params` below, this led me to beleive that `try_files $request_filename =404;` should work, but no dice. nginx still doesn't find the file, and returns 404.

So for right now, it will only work without any `try_files` directive. PHP finds the file, whereas try_files could not. I understand this may be a PHP security risk. Can anyone indicate how to move forward? The nginx logs don't contain anything relating to the failed try_files attempt, as far as I can see.

#### fastcgi_aparams

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING        $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD      $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE        $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH      $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI        $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT       $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL     $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE   CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE     nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR     $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT     $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR     $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT     $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME     $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS           $server_https;
```

Comment: According to this [forum post](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,2991,3070#msg-3070) this should work, but I couldn't get it to either. I suspect that the nested `location` block is interfering somehow.

Comment: Don't have your app in `/app` at all. It's pointless, loses you SEO points, and terribly confuses anybody who has to look at this. If you really want to go through this pain, you need to use `fastcgi_split_path_info`.

Answer (score 3):

In order to make it work, `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename` needs to be copied in the location block, like this:

```
location ^~ /app {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/www/website.com/content/public;
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
                try_files $uri =404; 
                # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
                fastcgi_split_path_info         ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_index               index.php;
        }
}
```

This is because in included configuration files, $request_filename dose not reflect the new alias, due to how nginx inherits configuration values between levels.

Answer (score 0):

Check your fastcgi_params. Most likely your SCRIPT_FILENAME is defined as $document_root$fastcgi_script_name which explicitly tells it not to consider alias (the $document_root part is the explicit part)

If you want to use alias with PHP you should probably define SCRIPT_FILENAME as $request_filename which takes alias into consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited the OP to contain my fastcgi_params. Looks like they are already configured as you suggest?

Comment: I think I misunderstood you then, is your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable the one showing up as /app still? Then that's expected behaviour as you have it defined it as `REQUEST_URI     $request_uri;`

Comment: I realized this morning that my question was horribly confusing, because "app" occurred in the path twice. I have edited the post so that it's now clear where "app" is the offending bit. I also added a section on what I have tried so far. Sorry for the initial confusion, and thank you for your assistance.